# Can't "Add New Item..." on project using Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++

When I create an empty console application the menu "Projects" disappears.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [sadpanda.us](http://sadpanda.us/images/370894-LGGBN7A.png))</sub>

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to go to View and click on Solution Explorer. This should display the Solution Menu.

[Edit: Are you sure you are not trying to load a C++ project]

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem.  If you go to File > new > File....  Then choose Visual C ++ on the left and then choose a C++ file you get a new item.

Did that work?